# Default value in the <select> bar

Tags: javascript, html, select, dynamic, onload

I know that there are similar questions but none of them change it onload dynamically.
The  bar on my website shows the first option of the  if I set it dynamically in onload function.
.value gives me the correct value but it doesnt get shown in the bar.
I cant use AJAX or JQuery because this is InLine Code on a website

```js
function init(){
    document.getElementById("selectRType").value = "Umfang";
}
```

```html
<body onload="init()">
<select style="width: 100%; " id="selectRType">
    <option value="Zeit">Zeit</option>
    <option value="Ressourcen">Ressourcen</option>
    <option value="Umfang">Umfang</option>
    <option value="Sonstiges">Sonstiges</option>
</select>
</body>
```

Comment: Actually, there is an issue in your DOM with the "init" function. Is it also present in your own HTML file ?

Comment: @Elikill58 oh sorry, no, i shortened the code by hand
It does everything it should do, except show the right value in the bar after loading

Comment: Ok ^^ I just changed into snippet, removed a unused method and it works. Maybe the issue can come from the other element value ? Can you check it, and mostly [edit] your post to make a [mre] as now it's not reproductible

Comment: @Elikill58 it works, even when i reproduce it exactly like I use it
I have no clue why it doesnt work on my site...

Comment: Do you have log ? I suggest you to use debugger or printer to know where it failed

Comment: @Elikill58 I did a workaround with localStorage. Once its saved, it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 0):

What if you try this instead?

```
var r = document.getElementById("selectRType");
r.options[2].selected = true;
```

Comment: Still doesnt work....

Comment: I imagine then there's something else on the page that's controlling it or the problem lies somewhere else in your code not shown here.

Answer (score 0):

In the end i used a  component provided by the site i am working on, which saves the selected option into the database. The localStorage solution didnt work that well after testing. I cannot provide any info on the  component, because i have no insight on the code in the background.

Comment: Can you precise your code, and more explain for further users?